# How to generate column with length property using JPA tools?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, eclipse-mars

I was generating Entity class for tables using JPA Tools in Eclipse Mars.It generate this

```
@Column(name="someColumn")
private String someColumn;
```

type of data member in Entity class which is of `varying(130)` type in databse. I have to manually edit every data member like this

```
@Column(name="someColumn",length=130)
private String someColumn;
```

by adding length in **Column** annotation. How to configure JPA Tools for generating data member with **length** automatically?